# addParam from database

Tags: php, javascript

My PHP is working fine but it's not placing the ip of my radio stations list on code below:

```
<div id="container"><a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.
<a href="http://www.shoutcheap.com/shoutcast/">shoutcheap shoutcast server hosting</a>
<a href="http://www.shoutcheap.com/icecast/">shoutcheap icecast server hosting</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var s1 = new SWFObject("http://www.shoutcheap.com/flashplayer/player.swf",
"ply","300","20","9","#FFFFFF");
s1.addParam("autostart","true");
s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
s1.addParam("flashvars",    "file=http://74.222.1.133:16682/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&volume=50&autostart=true");
s1.write("container");
</script>
```

I have a list with the ip like this one `(http://74.222.1.133:16682)` and I want to get them from the database and parse on this line s1.addParam("flashvars",    "file=........................../;stream.nsv&type=mp3&volume=50&autostart=true");

here's the php code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM lista WHERE nome='Jovem Pan FM'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($dados = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "Estação: ".$dados["ip"];
    }
?>
```

any idea why that's not working?

Comment: what does it `;stream.nsv` mean? may be this part is problematic?

Comment: it's part of the player function. The IP comes before the "/"